# Windows machine can't resolve DNS names from CentOS named server

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, windows-7, iptables, bind

Just setup a new Bind/Named DNS server on our CentOS server. I'm using Webmin to do most of the administration.

Once I've added some addresses to the zone, the addresses resolve just fine on the local machine when pinging.

But my Windows 7 box cannot resolve the addresses.

The Windows 7 box has a static IP and the DNS is setup to point to the CentOS box. The CentOS box is pingable and I can ssh to it just fine. I've used Webmin to open UDP and TCP port 53 on the CentOS box.

I'm not seeing anything show up in any logs regarding errors. What am I missing here?

Comment: use Windump or Ethereal to see what's going on UDP port 53, and/or tcpdump on the CentOS end.

Comment: Please answer your own question, then accept the answer rather than just updating the question - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The problem was Windows 7 DNS caching. After flushing/clearing the cache it was correctly resolving the names:

```
C:\> ipconfig /flushdns
```